# Benefit to duplicate mysql table to dispatch overload

Tags: mysql, database-performance, database-replication

**case 1:** 
i have a table A with 1 insert/per seconde .
From my admin i need to make some heavy read and delets on this table to perform some statistic and maintenance . 

Is it make sense to insert incoming data in 2 differents tables A and B , and use the table B for my administration. Goal is to not overload table A .

**case 2 :**
Another exemple to fully understand the logic , i have a table (tmpA) dedicated to fill search result . Each time there is a search , result is insert into this table and help for pagination.The night , olds results are delet .
actually i have 5 request per second for this table , so aproximativly 500 rows * 5 = 2500 rows /per second .

Is it make sens to creat more tables (tmpA , tmpB , tmpC ,etc..) to dispatch insert and avoid overload ?

**for case 1 , if make sens to duplicate** , 
whats is the difference with inserting "manualy" incoming  data in 2 (or more) differentes 
tables between use the mysql replication ?

Thanks to you,
jess

Comment: Comparing with your heavy writing, heavy non-locking read does unlikely impose heavy loading to the table. If you still want to have the 'table B' for reducing load or other purpose, replication could be an option. In term of performance I think 'manual insert' and replication are similar as replication is actually a series of stored procedure and trigger, which you can always implement your own. Making your own manual dual writing would allow you have more control over the process, if you don't need those replication options.

Comment: @albator What do you mean with maintenance and administration?

Comment: @ydoow Replication is not realized with procedures or triggers. This site is not a forum. If you don't know for sure, what you're talking about, don't talk ;)

Comment: @fancyPants by maintenance i mean some delet regulary ( i cannot perform it the night ). Each second i have a new member signup , so there is many write on its table , and in the same table and same time i need to delete many members on this tables ( moderation)

Comment: @fancyPants i edited for be more clear as possible

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda difficult to answer, as it depends on your setup hardware-wise. 
An insert per second isn't that much. A properly setup server should be able to handle it.

Reads on a table are non-blocking. so gathering info to do statistics (and assuming you don do the calculations for the statistics in the database) shouldn't influence the performance of your database.

Deletes on the other hand are blocking, and will add up to load on a table with heavy inserts.

**For Case 1**, I do not understand how you would want to split the load on different tables. Generally speaking, there's a database-server load, and not specifically a table load (unless we define blocking processes as table load).

I gather from the comments that Case 1 are user signups/registration. splitting user information over two tables is horrid from a maintenance perspective, plus the coupling of two tables that inevitably needs happen only increases overhead -load-, instead of decreasing it. Deleting data (users?) is also a major issue if the data is divided over two tables. *Can you explain how you see administering your data if this is divided over two tables? I'm probably missing something.*

Looking at the above, I do not recommend splitting this data between tables.
What I do recommend is:

- Use InnoDB as a table type. It has smaller locking than MyISAM (which does table locking?)
- Optimize your RAM/memory usage for MySQL. Proper memory settings allow for very quick reads and writes.
- Optimize your indexes. the `EXPLAIN` statement can show which ones are used for each query

**Case 2**
I don't fully understand the use case, but it might make sense to spit this data up into several tables. Depending on why you want to push the data in these temp tables, splitting might happen per user, keyword or other significant features.

Depending on the use case try limiting the search results (and thus utilizing pagination) through `LIMIT BY` statements. You don´t need store results for pagination that way, or store the results at all. Can you explain why you want to store these results? 2500 rows/sec is a lot.

**Replication** is a whole other topic, much more complicated and not achieved by copying tables, but by copying servers. I can't help you with that, never done it, as I never needed it. (my largest MySQL server was aprox. 80Gb large, 350 million rows, with inserts peaking at 224 rows per second)

*Can you paste the architecture of your tables you currently use, and some sample data? That might makes the cases at tad more clear.*